# Javascript object wrapper performance

Tags: javascript, performance

consider this test http://jsperf.com/query-wrappers

Does anyone have an idea **why is "jq wrapper (single)" test 3xs faster than the "direct call single" test**? (Chrome results)

It make no sense to me - I've tried replacing this.i with value 0 in "single" class and results don't change much.

The only way I see it is if the Browser has some kind of enhancing system for these cases...

I literally can't wrap my head around it :D

Comment: Do the relative efficiencies seem to change based on the number of elements, or does it seem to be around 3x faster regardless of the count?

Comment: There are a number of test cases with more or less expected results.
But my initial expection was than "direct call single" would have to be faster than "jq wrapper (single)" as the latest has one extra "step" with the unnecessary "for" overhead;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is strange:

```
function multiple(el){
  this.length = 0;
  for(var i=0;i<this.length;i++) this[this.length++] = el[i];
}
```

That's never going to do *anything* useful. You initialize the "length" property to zero, so the subsequent loop won't do anything at all.

Other places in the code seem to assume that "length" will be managed automatically. That, however, is only true for Array instances, which your objects cannot be.